# How to store a line number in variable (shell script,unix)?

Tags: unix

file.txt is as below :

```
gui : 789
gui : 789
gui : 789
gui : 789
abc : 120
```

The followibng gives o/p as

```
$ grep -n "gui : 789" file.txt | cut -f1 -d: 
1
2
3
4
```

If there are N number of such gui : 789 , how to store the line numbers of the same ?

Comment: Redirect the output to a file.

Comment: Are you asking how to compute `N`?

Comment: i've to store the o/p ( each line no. ) in a variable, which is further useful in next step. hw can i do it ?

Comment: You should ask more specific questions. What Unix shell? What format do you want the data to have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this awk 1 liner:

```
awk '/gui : 789/{print NR}' file
```

To process this inside a loop:

```
while read l
do
   echo $l
done < <(awk '/gui : 789/{print NR}' file)
```

**EDIT:** These command will work for any number of matches in the file. To store output of above line numbers in an array:

```
arr=( $(awk '/gui : 789/{print NR}' x) )
```

later on process these array elements as:

```
echo ${arr[0]}
echo ${arr[1]}
...
echo ${arr[5]}
```

Comment: @ anubhava : It prints the output as below which is same as i mentioned in the post
1
2
3
4

These line numbers want to be stored in individual variable as
a=1
b=2
c=3
d=4

Comment: @JackieJames: Please tell what do you mean by "generic" here and I can sure edit my answer to reflect that.

Comment: it should be applicable,if there are N number of lines like gui :789,and also o/p of each such line no. should store in individual variable.

Comment: These command will work for any number of matches in the file. Please check edit section for storing line numbers in an array. If there are huge number of matches in a line then it is better to iterate using while loop (as shown above) and push it into an array.

Comment: @ Anubhava : 
This works fine since because i'm directly inputting the data.    

    declare -a arr
    arr=( $(awk '/123456789/{print NR}' filename) )
    echo ${arr[0]}
    echo ${arr[*]}

    
Bt when i do as below, it doesn't work. Can u let me know how the parameter 'name' can be used int command below :
    
    echo  Enter your search string:  
    read name
    declare -a arr
    arr=( $(awk '/"$name"/{print NR}' filename )
    echo ${arr[0]}
    echo ${arr[*]}

Comment: @JackieJames: Its difficult to understand your comment from comments, I suggest posting your script and query as a separate question so that SO users can provide you fast answer.

Comment: @ Anubhava : I think my questions has crossed the target i guess. Is there any other possible ways where can i ask ? Plzee let me know.

Comment: You can simply post a new question and link this question as a reference and you will get immediate answers.

Comment: @ Anubhava : I posted a new question. Plzz hav a look at that.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
LINES=$(grep -n "gui : 789" file.txt | cut -f1 -d:)
```

The "LINES" variable will have: "1 2 3 4".

Note: your question was very generic. This answer will work for Bash or Korn Shell.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do processing with each line, you can do something like:

```
grep -n "gui : 789" file.txt | cut -f1 -d: | while read lineno; do
  : # process using $lineno
done
```